# Automatic enumerate list using eastern Arabic letters in beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate, enumitem, letters, right-to-left

Consider the MWE below:

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer-rl}
\babelprovide[import=ar, main,mapdigits]{arabic}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\title{مثال تجريبي}
\subtitle{نموذج}
\begin{document}

\section{اليوم الاول}
\subsection{مقدمة}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{لمحة تاريخية}
  \begin{enumerate}[label*=\arabic*.]
  \item الجملة الاولى
  \item الجملة الثانية
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item[ا.] تفرع اول
    \item[ب.] تفرع ثاني
    \item[جـ.] تفرع ثالث
    \end{enumerate}
  \item الجملة الثانية
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

**Output**
[image]

**Question**

I need to get the same output in Beamer without entering the sub-items manually (ا، ب، ج، د) these are the Hindi eastern Arabic letters, how to achieve that by having `enumitem` package generate that automatically just as the numbers, i.e. I don't want to put the letters by myself each time I have subitems list especially when the list is actually a long one. How to do that?

**Note**

tex engine is luatex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If things haven't changed, `enumitem` is not compatible with `beamer`. But the latter provides tools to configure lists. (Well, the 3rd item has a tatweel, while the default `abjad` doesn't, so I've added to `\babelprovide` an option to redefine it.)

```
\documentclass{beamer-rl}
\babelprovide[import, main,
 mapdigits,
 counters/abjad = ا ب جـ د ه‍ و
 ]{arabic}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\localecounter{abjad}{enumii}.}

\title{مثال تجريبي}
\subtitle{نموذج}

\begin{document}

\section{اليوم الاول}
\subsection{مقدمة}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{لمحة تاريخية}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item الجملة الاولى
  \item الجملة الثانية
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item تفرع اول
    \item تفرع ثاني
    \item تفرع ثالث
    \end{enumerate}
  \item الجملة الثانية
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the MWE works fine, but when I try to implement it on my actual beamer if throws an error: ERROR: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

--- TeX said ---
\labelenumi ->{\labelenumi 
                           }
l.230 \item ا...

Comment: strange enough that beamer won't complain if I provide the `[labe=\...]` argument after `\begin{enumerate}` i.e. like this `\begin{enumerate}[label=\...]`

Comment: Aha, I didn't notice that you removed `\usepackage{enumitem}` altogether from the preamble, sorry my... so now it works fine without loading this package.

Comment: I wonder now without loading this package, how to change the color of the font of the items, I mean how to pass it as an argument per list using `enumerate`?

Comment: I am using now `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\textcolor{orange}{\arabic{enumi}.}}` from preamble, but I am asking about a local way to change color.